# How to select a value from an angular dropdown in C# with selenium

Tags: c#, angular, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click a value from an angular dropdown. When I click on the dropdown arrow, an option becomes available to 'Make Primary Contact' which I want to click using Selenium WebDriver and C#

I have tried the following

.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown)

Also I tried locating the element by XPath but as it is dynamic, this isn't working either.

Here is the HTML

```
<section>
<div class="entry-box">
    <input class="inv-input" [ngModel]="value?.ItemValue" (ngModelChange)="updatePhoneNumber($event)"/>

     <div class="caret-container" (click)="toggleDropDown()">
        <span *ngIf="value?.IsPrimary">{{'contactDetailsTab.selectedPrimaryLabel' | translate}}</span>
        <img class="select-icon" src="/assets/app/caret-dark.svg">
    </div> 
</div>
<ng-container *ngIf="showDropDown">
    <div  class="dropdown-container">
        <ul #dropDown tabIndex="-1" class="dropdown" (blur)="onBlur()">
            <li *ngIf="!value?.IsPrimary" (mousedown)="setPrimary(true)">{{'contactDetailsTab.makePrimaryContact' | translate}}</li>
            <li *ngIf="value?.IsPrimary" (mousedown)="setPrimary(false)">{{'contactDetailsTab.removePrimaryContact' | translate}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</ng-container>
</section>
```

Comment: Since it's custom dropdown can you provide code that handles usage of arrow keys?

Comment: Possibly by using a css selector? . dropdown option:first-child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[contains(., 'Make Primary Contact')]"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the SelectElement function of Selenium:

```
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("your Xpath here"))).SelectByText("Make Primary Contact");
```

[Here you have more info about SelectElement](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_SelectElement.htm)

Is the best way to deal with dropdowns and check the values inside. You also can SelectByIndex or whatever is more suitable for you.